# How to develop a package on a Rstudio server with no rights?

Tags: r, build, package, administration, rstudio-server

I want to develop a private local package on a RStudio server but it seems configured in a way that makes that impossible.

I know that as a simple user I cannot install a package from the outside (eg. CRAN or git). But I have been thinking that I can make my own in order to build and use a set of private tools.

I can create a new package project but when I want to build it, I have the following message:

```
* installing to library ‘/srv/commun/rstudio-server/libpath_root/R/library/4.1.2’
Erreur : ERROR: no permission to install to directory ‘/srv/commun/rstudio-server/libpath_root/R/library/4.1.2’

Exited with status 1.
```

Is there any workaround other than sourcing files to build a set of functions?

What can I ask to the RStudio server administrator to allow me to make a local package?

Comment: https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/215733837-Managing-libraries-for-RStudio-Workbench-RStudio-Server suggests that you can set a personal library location using `.libPaths(...)` just like you can with a local R.

Comment: This is likely a duplicate a dozen times over.  First entry of `.libPaths()` has to be writeable.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, here is a comprehensive answer:

1. We must create a writeable dir for that eg. `~/R-local-lib/`

---

2. When building/installing the package, you have to add the following:

```
R CMD install --library='~/R-local-lib/'
```

One can set that in the Project Options of the RStudio menus.

---

3. Then you add this line to your `~/.Rprofile`:

```
.libPaths(c("~/R-local-lib", .libPaths))
```